# Spring Boot RestTemplate postForEntity but with null body

Tags: spring-boot, http-post, resttemplate

I want to make a Post request, which has no body (null) for testing purposes.

```
ResponseEntity<Script> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, null, Script.class);
```

This works fine, when the body is not null. But why doesn't it work with null? (I also tried `""` instead of null ->same exception). Also, when I do a Postman Post request with a null body my application works, so the error has to be within the code above.

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 : [{"timestamp":"2021-06-17T09:35:53.289+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","path":"/application"}]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:819)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:751)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:486)
    at
```

Is there another way to make a (null-body) Post request with restTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change `null` to `Null.class`